# cant run pm2 process

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2

I want to create a PM2 process to run my react app, (if a do a serve -s build it will stop working once I disconnect from instance) but getting this error already tried to rename the main but not working

0|citas    | }
0|citas    | Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/build/main.js not supported.
0|citas    | main.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
0|citas    | Instead rename main.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

I tried to rename this /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/build/main.js but did not work

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are encountering issue when trying to your react app with PM2, and you also tried to rename the main file. Here, you should follow some steps:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

In your react app's root directory create a PM2 configuration file named **pm2.config.js** or **pm2.json**

```js
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "my-react-app",
      "script": "node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js",
      "cwd": "./",
      "args": "start",
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- "name" is the name you want to give to your PM2 process.
- "script" specifies the script that will start your React app. It's set to start.js from the react-scripts package.
- "cwd" specifies the current working directory.
- "args" passes the command-line argument "start" to the script.
- "exec_mode" is set to "fork" for running in fork mode.
- "env" sets the NODE_ENV environment variable to "production" to run your app in production mode.

**Then run the command**

```
pm2 start pm2.json
```

**replace p2.json with your configuration file name**

To check the process status:

```
pm2 list
```

Answer (score 0):

To run your React app with PM2 and resolve the ESM/CommonJS compatibility issue,

Create a **pm2.config.js** file

set **"type"** in your project's **package.json** to **"commonjs"**.

Then, start your app with PM2 using

```
pm2 start pm2.config.js
```